# Getting Notifications of iOS notifications center

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Can I get the Notifications of the iOS notifications center? I have a RF that needs to read all the notifications of the iPhone.

Comment: When you say RF, do you mean Bluetooth?  If so, you can use ANCS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The iOS sandbox makes sure apps can only access their own data, not every notification that comes to your device.

As a user, I really don't want apps to read my email.